How to perform RPA+HF calculation in VASP?
I want to conduct some accuracy comparisons of widely used exchange functionals such as PBE-D3, r2SCAN against against reference first-principles many-body electronic structure method of random phase approximations (RPA+HF). How to achieve this in VASP? I found one page called ACDFT/RPA calculation in VASP wiki. https://www.vasp.at/wiki/index.php/ACFDT/RPA_calculations
